# What type of collision resolution is chosen for HashTable/Dictionary implementation in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable, collision

As we know there are 2 classical strategies to collision resolution: Separate chaining and Open addressing.

I'm wondering which one was chosen for HashTable/Dictionary in .net.

Or there were used some other strategy?

Comment: Good question. I probably would never have looked up that paper if you hadn't posted this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's all described in this paper on the MSDN : [An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> ...collision resolution technique called rehasing, which is the
>   technique used by the .NET Framework's Hashtable class. In the final
>   section, we'll look at the Dictionary class, which uses a collision
>   resolution technique knows as chaining.
>   ....
>
> ... Rehasing works as follows: there is a set of hash different
>   functions, H1 ... Hn, and when inserting or retrieving an item from
>   the hash table, initially the H1 hash function is used. If this leads
>   to a collision, H2 is tried instead, and onwards up to Hn if needed.
>   The previous section showed only one hash function, which is the
>   initial hash function (H1). The other hash functions are very similar
>   to this function, only differentiating by a multiplicative factor. In
>   general, the hash function Hk is defined as:

```
 Hk(key) = [GetHash(key) + k * (1 + (((GetHash(key) >> 5) + 1) %  (hashsize – 1)))] % hashsize
```

> The Dictionary class differs from the Hashtable class in more ways
>   than one. In addition to being strongly-typed, the Dictionary also
>   employs a different collision resolution strategy than the Hashtable
>   class, using a technique referred to as chaining. Recall that with
>   probing, in the event of a collision another slot in the list of
>   buckets is tried. (With rehashing, the hash is recomputed, and that
>   new slot is tried.) With chaining, however, a secondary data structure
>   is utilized to hold any collisions. Specifically, each slot in the
>   Dictionary has an array of elements that map to that bucket. In the
>   event of a collision, the colliding element is prepended to the
>   bucket's list.

Remember only the first sentence is my own :-)

Comment: A `Dictionary` doesn't have a secondary data structure to hold collisions. At least in C# 4 it doesn't.

Comment: @Gabe : Could you provide another explaination or link maybe ?

Comment: @Gabe: Could you elaborate? That looks like a pretty accurate description of `Dictionary<K,V>` to me. My understanding is that each bucket contains a linked-list of elements (and in the event of no collisions that linked-list will contain a single element).

Comment: It is not a linked list.  Same strategy as List<>, it simply reallocates the bucket by doubling the array size.  Use Reflector to see this, Dictionary<>.Resize() method.

Comment: @Gabe: actually, it does, except the 'secondary data structure' is stored in-line with the data itself. I'll be doing a blog post on this soon, as I've been looking at what exactly `Dictionary` does recently.

Comment: While the linked document provides a nice abstract description of a hash table with chaining, it helps very little in understanding the actual implementation of `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Gabe: I've written a blog post on it: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2011/09/16/103362.aspx

Answer (score 5):

That's actually a really interesting question; I've just done a [blog post](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2011/09/16/103362.aspx) on how `Dictionary` is implemented behind-the-scenes. I may cover `Hashtable` in a later one.

Comment: That's very nice. You should post a summary in your answer.

Comment: It needs diagrams to explain it properly; I'm not sure I can summarise it adequately... :/

Comment: By all means, include the diagrams. You can upload images by pressing Ctrl+G.

Comment: Thank you so much for awesome blog post. It makes totally clear Dictionary's implementation.